# Странное подключение js файла

Tags: javascript

Что это, после знака вопроса, get параметр?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/index.js?167"></script>
```

Comment: @Dirtez, не забудьте принять ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Да - после символа `?` GET параметр.
Нужен для того, чтобы не кешировались на клиенте, то есть исправил js файл, исправь версию (ревизию), а то возможны глюки у клиента.